# Non ASCII Characters being converted to squares

Tags: php, ascii

I've got the following code which searches a string for Non ASCII characters and returns it via an AJAX query.

```
$asciistring = $strDescription;
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($asciistring); $i++) {  
    if (ord($asciistring[$i]) > 127){
        $display_string .= $asciistring[$i];
    }
}
```

If $strDescription contains £ (character # 156) the above code works fine. However, I want to separate each Non ASCII character found with a comma. When I modify my code below, it converts the £ character into squares.

```
$asciistring = $strDescription;
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($asciistring); $i++) {  
    if (ord($asciistring[$i]) > 127){
        $display_string .= $asciistring[$i] . ", ";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – you are operating on single bytes in a string that uses a multi-byte character encoding, which of course is bound to go wrong.

Comment: Let me be more specific: What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You assume `1 character = 1 byte`.

This assumption is wrong when it comes to UTF-8 / UTF-16 etc.

UTF-8 e.a. consist of multi-byte chars: `1 character = 1 to 3 bytes`.

So, your loop over 8-bit-bytes can not handle any UTF-8 chars.

Use the [mb_...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions instead - multibyte string functions.

Additionaly: converting ASCII to UTF-8 and vice versa is

1. in general not needed
2. will always result in certain characters not available in either
   encoding (i.e. the € sign is one of them)
3. will be a maintenance nightmare on the long run

My recommendation: it's worth the effort to switch all and everything from dev to production to entirely use UTF-8. All problems are gone afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you two way. At first use utf8_decode. You can try these

```
$asciistring = 'a£bÂc£d';
$asciistring =  utf8_decode($asciistring);
```

First way preg_match_all

```
if (preg_match_all('/[\x80-\xFF]/', $asciistring, $matches)) {
    $display_string = implode(',', $matches[0]);
}
```

2nd way as you wrote

```
$display_string = array();
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($asciistring); $i++) {
    if (ord($asciistring[$i]) > 127)
    {
        $display_string[] = $asciistring[$i];
    }
}
$display_string = implode(',', $display_string);
```

Both give me the same **output**

```
£,Â,£
```

I think you will be helpful!

Comment: [Does not work](http://codepad.org/QQ76IW3e) somehow the £ gets split in the loop in two characters and when you separate them it breaks as OP describes

Comment: Nice idea but as kingkero says, the result is the same.

Comment: Instead of getting 2 squares, I now get 1 per Non ASCII character -  See here http://codepad.org/MIDjAnG3

Comment: Sorry @Dion, it gives me the output as string(5) "£,Â,£". my PHP version 5.3.5